# How do I set locale information for all user accounts (including system user & network service user) in windows 2016

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, locale, packer

I am currently working on building an AWS AMI for a Windows 2016 base image. I'm doing this by creating a template for packer and I'm having issues getting the system and default user accounts to have their Locale set properly.

I need to get the Locale set to en-AU (the AWS AMIs default to en-US).

So far I've tried the following Powershell commandlets without any success:

```
# Update Locale settings
Set-Culture en-AU
Set-WinSystemLocale en-AU
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-AU -Force
```

The above only seems to work for the user that packer runs as.

I'm using Inspec to validate the result with the following tests:

```
control "validate-locale-settings" do 
    # Check that the WinSystemLocale is set to en-AU
    describe command('Get-WinSystemLocale') do
       its('stdout') { should match /en-AU/ }
    end

    describe registry_key('Timezone','HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation') do
        it { should have_property_value 'DaylightName', :string, 'AUS Eastern Daylight Time' }
        it { should have_property_value 'TimeZoneKeyName', :string, 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' }
    end

    # Check that the test user is being set to en-AU
    describe command('(Get-ItemProperty "REGISTRY::HKLM\Control Panel\International").LocaleName') do
        its('stdout') { should match /en-AU/ }
    end
end
```

The test will pass if I run the inspec test as the packer user, but I run them as the administrator user they fail.

I'm looking for a scripted equivalent to the control panel 'copy settings' button that you can use via control panel.

[administrative tab under control panel/region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lHFJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a Windows Server Core 2022 installation so there's no simple UI solution like "Copy Settings" from the Regional Settings tab.
I wanted a Powershell or CLI solution and like you say it can be applied for the user but not copied across to all users.

For that I found help from an article by Lewis Roberts on his blog
https://www.lewisroberts.com/2017/03/01/set-language-culture-timezone-using-powershell/

You need to use `control.exe` to import a regional settings XML file.
The following will be for `en-GB` UK region so adjust it to fit your requirements.

Save the following XML to a file called `UKRegion.xml` or whatever you want.

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend"> 
<!--User List-->
<gs:UserList>
    <gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<!-- user locale -->
<gs:UserLocale> 
    <gs:Locale Name="en-GB" SetAsCurrent="true"/> 
</gs:UserLocale>
<!-- system locale -->
<gs:SystemLocale Name="en-GB"/>
<!-- GeoID -->
<gs:LocationPreferences> 
    <gs:GeoID Value="242"/> 
</gs:LocationPreferences>
<gs:MUILanguagePreferences>
    <gs:MUILanguage Value="en-GB"/>
    <gs:MUIFallback Value="en-US"/>
</gs:MUILanguagePreferences>
<!-- input preferences -->
<gs:InputPreferences>
    <!--en-GB-->
    <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0809:00000809" Default="true"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Then import it using the following command (Powershell formatted):

```
& $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"UKRegion.xml`""
```

You still need a reboot but this worked for me and set the ASPNET workers to use `en-GB` locale by default without having to set it in code or in the web.config.
This was particularly useful for me as I am using it to set up EC2 instances using launch templates so many other solutions don't work.